# Blender my image texture is blurry

Tags: image, textures, blender

Before I render (in cycles) my steam logo sticker looks perfect but when i render my logo looks pixley
 [Before I render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dzdi2.png)

[After I render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jH8wI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your rendering set to 100% up from the default 50%? That's the first thing that comes to mind.  Got screenshot of the render settings?

Comment: That helps alot but is there a way I can make it look more like the before render image?

Comment: You may also want to play with the aliasing, also in the render settings.  Check, turn on, Anti-Aliasing and turn up the samples, see if that helps.